# What is the meaning of the operator projection in quantum mechanic

Tags: operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

Let's have a vector $B_1$ which lies in the $xz$ plane forming an angle $\theta$ with $z$ axis. Let $S_\theta$ be the projection of the operator **S** along $B_1$.

**Question 1:**

How can i write $S_\theta$ as a linear combination of $S_x$ and $S_z$?

**Question 2:**

What is the meaning of the operator projection? The linear operator $S$ (Spin operator) is a linear transformation between two vectorial spaces, it is not a vector, how can it have a projection and components (like $S_x$, $S_y$, $S_z$)? Is like talking about the components of a function $f(x)$, what's the meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear this is a matter of language, namely parsing out the two vector spaces involved, *V* and *W*, which are in a Cartesian product: they do not "know" about each other. *V* is the two dimensional plane, *xz*, while *W* is left unspecified here.

Your $\vec B_1= |B_1| (\sin\theta, \cos\theta)^T$ is strictly a vector in *V*, while the vector operator $\vec {\mathbf S}= ({\mathbf S}_x,{\mathbf S}_z)^T$ is a doublet of operators as written, each one of which maps vectors in *W* to vectors in *W*.

The projection is
$$
\vec {\mathbf S}_\theta = \vec B_1\cdot \vec {\mathbf S}/|B_1| = \sin\theta ~  {\mathbf S}_x+ \cos\theta ~{\mathbf S}_z~, 
$$
now a *scalar* in *V*, and it is simply an operator mapping vectors in *W* to vectors in *W*.  You've managed to decouple the two vector spaces.

A similar constructions characterizes the celebrated dot product of a direction vector to the [Pauli vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Pauli_vector) which results in an operator acting on spinors (complex 2-vectors in *W*).